# In Leaflet style function, option to prevent display completely?

Tags: leaflet

In a Leaflet style function, is there an option which completely prevents the display of a feature? In other words (pseudocode):

```
function styleFunc(feature) {
    if (feature.properties['blah'] == 1) {
        return {
            color: 'red';
        }
    } else {
        return {
            DISPLAY: NONE;
        }
    }
}
```

What can I use instead of `DISPLAY: NONE` to prevent the given features from rendering? I don't just want to make them transparent, since I guess then popups etc will still operate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean the `style` option of `L.GeoJSON`, for `L.Path`s like polylines and circles?

Setting both `stroke` and `fill` to `false` will work nicely. i.e.:

```
return { stroke: false, fill: false };
```

For the `L.Canvas` renderer this avoids the calls to `ctx.fill()` and `ctx.stroke()`, which are the ones that really take CPU time. I don't really know what the behaviour for `L.SVG` will be, but I expect big parts of the rendering pipeline to be skipped.

Also be aware that setting the opacity of a `L.Path` to `0` makes it clickable, but disabling either the stroking or the filling will effectively prevent that layer from dispatching any events.

There is currently (Leaflet 1.0.2) no way to make the layers disappear completely. If you need this, consider iterating through the elements inside your `L.GeoJSON`, and removing those which don't meet your criteria.

Comment: Works perfectly - thank you. Wasn't aware that there would also be a performance benefit.